# Using bit masks to control large set of fields in a form with categories

Tags: javascript, php, bitwise-operators

I've only used bitwise operators and masks once in SQL Server many years ago. It was simple 2/4/8/16 flag switch. This time, after having read numerous articles and Wikipedia article about masks, I still can't wrap my head around this. It could be that my thinking here is totally incorrect and I can't use masks but so far I also didn't find a definitive reason why not.

I have **4 categories** in my form in PHP with the following values:

```php
$category1 = ["one", "two", "three"];
$category2 = ["one", "two", "three"];
$category3 = ["one", "two"];
$category4 = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
```

Then I have a gargantuan number of checkboxes that I need to show/hide depending on whether they belong to a specific combination of those categories. They can belong to many at the same time.

Let's say I have this one checkbox:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="some_name[]" value="some_value" />
```

Now, this checkbox can be displayed in any of these combinations:

```
category1 = "one" AND category2 = "two" AND category3 = "one" AND category4 = "four"
category1 = "one" AND category2 = "one" AND category3 = "one" AND category4 = "one"
category1 = "one" AND category2 = "one" AND category3 = "two" AND category4 = "three"
```

I've tried assigning values to categories first, so that:

```
category1_value = 1 + <array_index_of_the_value+1>
category2_value = 10 + <array_index_of_the_value+1>
category3_value = 100 + <array_index_of_the_value+1>
category4_value = 1000 + <array_index_of_the_value+1>
```

But I can't figure out **how to set one value/class/data attribute** that would allow me to perform bitmask operation to **show** it when a specific combination of the categories is selected.

Then I tried multiplying each number but this wouldn't even give me unique values for each combination, same if I applied `2`, `4`, `8`, and `16` respectively to each category, and then just multiply each combination.

While writing this post I started doubting whether I can even do it in one mask. Because they're not cascading but categorical. Meaning the higher number wouldn't allow all **"lower"** combination.

However I might be wrong and perhaps there is a way. Any help would be appreciated.

--edit

Actually to make things even more complicated the `$category4` is actually a cascaded category, which means a value of `four` should display all `one`, `two` , and `three` as well.

Comment: For one, I don't see a single bitwise operator in your question. You should probably [review the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php). Second, unless you're _severely_ constrained for storage efficiency [and have excess sanity you'd like to get rid of] I would recommend _not_ using bitfields in 2020.

Comment: Yes, I haven't got to do any operations just yet because I'm trying to come up with the logic first

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure of the full context of your problem, but if you're looking to uniquely identify a combination of all four categories with one number, then you'll need a 12 digit binary number.  For example...

```
$category1 = [ 1 << 11,  1 << 10, 1 << 9 ];
$category2 = [ 1 << 8, 1 << 7, 1 << 6 ];
$category3 = [ 1 << 5, 1 << 4 ];
$category4 = [ 1 << 3, 1 << 2, 1 << 1, 1 << 0 ];  // Ie, 0b1000, 0b100, 0b10, 0b1
```

...such that...

```
category1 = "one" AND category2 = "two" AND category3 = "one" AND category4 = "four"
category1 = "one" AND category2 = "one" AND category3 = "one" AND category4 = "one"
category1 = "one" AND category2 = "one" AND category3 = "two" AND category4 = "three"
```

...can now be represented as...

```
if ( v === 0b100010100001 || v === 0b100100101000 || v === 0b100100010010 )
```

It's easier to visualize this by first writing the binary number in tuples by category.  Eg the last of the three lines is...

- category1 == "one":   100
- category2 == "one":   100
- category3 == "two":   01
- category4 == "three": 0010

...and putting these together we arrive at...

`0b100100010010`

Hope this helps.